# website freezes for 30 secs in IE 6,7,8 but no freeze in chrome or ff - why?

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a website that loads lightning fast in Firefox, Chrome, and other browsers, but when you load it in IE 6, 7, 8 IE hangs (freezes) for about 20 seconds, but then finishes loading and everything is fine until I click on a new page where the freeze cycle repeats. NOTE in IE 9 it seems to load ok, as expected.

the site is

niseko-village.com

Can someone take a look and see what's happening?

Thanks,
Blue

Comment: Use Fiddler to watch your network traffic. Use the F12 Developer Tools' Script tab to profile the JavaScript and look for blocking behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was that I was the code I was using had a bug. If you use Colorbox for image galleries, then all you need to do is upload to the newest version, which fixes the bug.